# Get product attribute value in new_grid.phtml magento2

Tags: magento2

I have problem with getting attribute value in new_grid.phtml. If i make it like this:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct()
echo $_product->getData('attr_name') ?>
```

Page generating to this place, and after just blank page.

Please show me other option, or maybe i have mistakes in my code.

Here is the place in new_grid.phtml:

```
<div class="product-img-block">
<a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
<?php echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml(); ?>

/* my code: */
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
<img src="<?php echo $_product->getData('attr_name') ?>" />
</a>
```

Please help.

*Anwer to  Keyur Shah:*

**it is code from custom_home.xml**

```
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/front-slider.phtml" before="main.content"/>

<container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
<container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>

<container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
            </container>
</container>
```

**In front-slider.phtml i get the new_grid.phtml by code:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("all_products")->setProductsCount("6")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: What is the block type of `new_grid.phtml` ?

Comment: You mean in .xml? i ansvered in my question.

Comment: yes, how you called your phtml file ? Please share

Comment: i ansvered in my question, plese update it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755598/get-product-attribute-value-in-new-grid-phtml-magento - here is the answer on this question.